# Shared library and rpath

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I cannot make rpath work properly and make my binary to search for the library in the specified folder:

I have 3 very simple files:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <func.h>
int main() {
    testing();
return 1;
}
```

**func.h**

```
void testing();
```

**func.c**

```
#include "func.h"
void testing(){

    printf(testing\n");
}
```

Then I proceed to create a **shared library** as it follows:

```
gcc -c -fpic func.c -o ../release/func.o
gcc -shared -o ../release/lib/lib_func.so ../release/func.o
```

And then **compile the program**:

```
gcc main.c ../release/lib/lib_time_mgmt.so -Wl,-rpath=/home/root/ -o ../release/main
```

I receive the next warning:

```
main.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘testing’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
testing();
```

But besides it, the program works fine.

However, my problem is that if now I want to move the library to /home/root (as specified in **rpath**) it does not work and the library is still searched only in the path specified when I compiled the **main.c** file which is **../release/lib/lib_time_mgmt.so**

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:** After accepting the answer, I leave here the exact line as I used it and made it work for whoever might find it useful:

```
gcc main.c -L/home/root -Wl,-rpath,'/home/root/' -l:libtime_mgmt -o ${OUT_FILE}
```

Note: the rpath was used with the path betwen simple '. Not sure if that was the reason why it was not working before, but it worked this way now.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Doesn't look like your main program includes the header associated with your library

Comment: @Attie you are right, It was a typo when writing the code in stackoverflow. The original code is fine.

Comment: BTW: nowadays `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘testing’` should be considered as an error.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It is Ubuntu.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You are right, that prevents the warning to appear (although the program was working fine)

However I still have the main problem, which is that as long as I place the library in the final path /home/root/ it is not found anymore by the rpath flag

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes you are right, but fixing it does not actually solve the main problem of the path set in rpath. (However, it is already fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpath` is not used at compile time, but rather at link/runtime... thus you probably need to use both of these:

- `-L /home/root` - to link correctly at build time
- `-Wl,-rpath=/home/root` - to link correctly at run-time

You should use the `-l ${lib}` flag to link with libraries, don't specify their path as an input.

In addition to this, convention states that the libraries are named `libNAME.so` - e.g:

- `-l func` will try to link with `libfunc.so`
- `-l time_mgmt` will try to link with `libtime_mgmt.so`

Once you've addressed the above points, try the following:

```
gcc main.c -L/home/root -Wl,-rpath=/home/root -lfunc -ltime_mgmt -o ${OUT_FILE}
```

As a final point, I'd advise that you try not to use `rpath`, and instead focus on installing libraries in the correct places.

---

Unrelated to your question, but worth noting. Your use of `#include <...>` vs `#include "..."` is questionable. See: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: Maybe just link to an existing topic about that instead, since it isn't the main point of the question.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Indeed, your clarifications made me understand the topic deeper and understand the reason of my mistake.

However, although I am not totally sure, I think it was not working initially also due to some typo problem in the rpath. I used this format  now: rpath , ' $PATH ' and it worked.

I leave here the complete line for whoever might need it:

gcc main.c -L/home/root -Wl,-rpath,'/home/root/' -l:libtime_mgmt -o ${OUT_FILE}